# Should I elide inner or outer parentheses in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, coding-style

In Ruby, is there a preference for which level of parentheses to elide, or does it depend on the situation (in which case, what guidelines should be followed)? Sources are appreciated.

For example, is either

```
do_something do_something_else(...)
```

or

```
do_something(do_something_else ...)
```

better than the other?

Answer (score 2):

You want a rule to decide when to omit parentheses and when not. And that should be based on the method. (It is cumbersome to base the rule depending on the context, i.e., always omit the innermost parentheses, or always omit the outermost parentheses., etc.)

And there are methods that are usually only used at the outermost level (i.e., do not become an argument of another method call), as opposed to no/few methods that only appear as the innermost level. Typical examples of the former are DSL methods (methods that are conventionally used without parentheses like `puts`, `p` can be considered parts of the DSL provided by Ruby itself).

Once you decide to base the rule on what the method is, it follows naturally that you would be omitting the outermost parentheses that appear with particular methods.

Comment: Do you have a source, just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

This is a primarily opinion-based question, but [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) is a good (best?) reference when style-related questions appear.

Comment: I can't find the answer in the Style Guide... did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it should be consistent with rest of the `assert` in tests, and [looking at way asserts are used in Rails tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=assert) (i.e. with no parenthesis), it will be apt to use

```
assert method(param1, param2, etc)
```

Comment: `assert` was just an example. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria Same convention can be carried forward to rest of the functions as well, given that style guide does not have any particular guidelines on this matter.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria Which source?  The link in answer will take you to Rails Github search.

Comment: I mean a more general source than just Rails tests. Sorry for not clarifying.